# Redirect after data insertion in laravel with success message

Tags: laravel

Hello guyzz I want to redirect back to form for new data entry which is actually form.blade.php view. I can see the data inserted successfully but how I can redirect with success message. my code is given.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $sname = $request->input('sname');
   $fname = $request->input('fname');
   $gradyear = $request->input('gradyear');
   $phone = $request->input('phone');
   $email = $request->input('email');
   $paddress = $request->input('paddress');
   $prog = $request->input('prog');
   $job = $request->input('job');
   $org = $request->input('org');
   $position = $request->input('position');

   $data = array(
       'sname' => $sname,
       "fname" => $fname,
       "gradyear" => $gradyear,
       "phone" => $phone,
       "email" => $email,
       "paddress" => $paddress,
       "prog" => $prog,
       "job" => $job,          
       "org" => $org,
       "position" => $position
   );

   DB::table('tests')->insert($data);
   echo "Data inserted Successfully";
}
```

Comment: check my answer, this should redirect after you hit the store method

Answer (score 2):

On the controller after the code

```
return back()->with('status', 'successfully inserted');
```

On the form view

```
 @if(session('status')
    {{ session('status') }}
    @endif
```

You can format your message in the CSS you choose

Answer (score 0):

In Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    return back()->with('success', 'Data inserted Successfully');
}
```

In Blade:

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: on click how i can redirect?? it does not show any message that data is inserted successfully

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the above code is working the way you want, you can redirect with flashed session data:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $sname = $request->input('sname');
   $fname = $request->input('fname');
   $gradyear = $request->input('gradyear');
   $phone = $request->input('phone');
   $email = $request->input('email');
   $paddress = $request->input('paddress');
   $prog = $request->input('prog');
   $job = $request->input('job');
   $org = $request->input('org');
   $position = $request->input('position');

   $data = array(
       'sname' => $sname,
       "fname" => $fname,
       "gradyear" => $gradyear,
       "phone" => $phone,
       "email" => $email,
       "paddress" => $paddress,
       "prog" => $prog,
       "job" => $job,          
       "org" => $org,
       "position" => $position);

   DB::table('tests')->insert($data);

   return back()->with('status', 'Data inserted Successfully!');

}
```

And inside your blade file you can render with something like:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

---

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data